# My users can't unsubscribe themselves from (or subscribe to) smart groups from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, smartgroups

I am running 4.4.2 of Wordpress with Civi 4.6.10. I have a test site (WP 4.4.2, Civi 4.6.4) that works fine with the same set up. I have set up a profile with a groups field, and 2 public groups, one "dumb" and one smart. I am able to use the profile to unsubscribe from the regular group, but ticking (or unticking) the smart group has no effect on the membership of that group. Is this a regression that anyone is aware of? Or perhaps I have missed something in the set up?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Having written the below as an 'answer' I am less certain it is since it seems to raise more questions but will leave as such for now.

A contacts who is 'in' a Smart Group, is not 'added' to the Smart Group in the same way as they are to a General Group.

Hence I would not expect such a contact to see the checkbox for the Group 'ticked' when they go to the Profile.

Ie when I go to http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=16&reset=1 I do not see the group 'name like lan' checked, so it cannot be unchecked.

Does that make sense in your situation.

if lan does tick that group, then he gets sent an email for the double opt-in.

But when i Search within that Group for members Pending, it shows me all 11 contacts which I did not expect

11 Contacts 
Group(s) In name like lan ...AND...
Group Status 'Pending'

Wondering if the latter is a bug but not digging on other sites to prove outcome with older versions.

Comment: I have the double opt-in option turned off, so there is no email, and the smart group status should go straight to Added. I have confirmed this to work on 4.6.4, but I cannot get it to work on 4.6.10. On 4.6.4 I can successfully add and remove myself from a smart group using a profile.

Comment: If it is something you can verify on an earlier version then it should be added as an issue in JIRA. If you had the werewithall to take a dev site up through each upgrade and spot when it stopped working that would like help determine what broke it. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: unless of course there are any additional extensions etc that you are adding to your 4.6 mix that might interfere, but seemed like I was close to replicating it on demo, but didn't have the 4.6.4 version to compare to.